# Share image to another app using Intent in android

Tags: android, share

I want to share image and text to another app but i'm getting file format not supported when i'm using this code please help...

```
 Uri picUri = Uri.parse("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/image-slider-2.jpg");
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi There...");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, picUri);
            shareIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image...."));
```

Comment: Why not just share the uri as a string?

Comment: i tried it doesn't works the bellow code works posted by@Nilesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {


    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap myBitmap=null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        //do stuff

    }
}

 Bitmap returned_bitmap = new myTask().execute().get()



Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "download this image");
String bitmapPath = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), returned_bitmap,"title", null);
Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share image via..."));
```

Comment: I'm getting file not found exception when i'm using the first code that you have send....

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/image-slider-2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: you want to send just image url or image to other apps

Comment: image with some kind of message

Comment: I have changed my code accordingly but i'm getting fatal exception android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: just change the return bitmap; to retun myBitmap;

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation for `EXTRA_STREAM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) says that the `Uri` needs to have a `content` scheme. `file` usually also works, at least on Android 6.0 and older. Few apps will expect an `http` URL.