# I need to share a firebase image from url using picasso but my solution is not working so far

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

This is my code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
```

Getting the image

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(feedItemList.get(position).getImage());
                Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getImage()).into(customViewHolder.imageView);
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        feedItem.getTitle() + "\n" +


                                "\n \n" + "See more " +
                                " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?com.truth.origicheck.memeshare");
                sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                sendIntent.setType("image/png");

                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                mContext.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

I need to send the image and text

Comment: this will help you my friend https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506185/7666442

Comment: @Nilu I am using firebase and Picasso....

Comment: than whats the issue doenload bitmap from url and share it like in my ans

Comment: @Nilu String bitmapPath = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), returned_bitmap,"title", null);......that line I cant resolve the ContentResolver and returned bitmap

Comment: you are getting image url  or Uri from storage

Comment: @Nil yes and then using Picasso

Comment: means **URL** of image m i right

Comment: @Nil Yes you are right...

Comment: try this `String bitmapPath = Images.Media.insertImage(yourActivity.this.getContentResolver(), returned_bitmap,"title", null);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162213/discussion-between-vincent-macharia-and-nilu).